# search a colum for a value, copy the cell in the previous colum and the paste it to the first available blank in a range. All on a loop

Tags: vba, loops, search, copy, paste

So i'm wanting to search column e4:e70.  I want to search for the word "hol" and then copy the name from the value from the same row but column before.  I then want to paste this in the first available blank space between range Q36:Q47.  I then want to delete the original data

So I can get it to search the column in a loop, find what it needs to find.  and then clear the contents.  i'm struggling to get it to plave it in the first available space.

```
   set rng = range("e3:e70")
   for each cl in range
   if cl.value="hol" then cl.offset(, -1).clear contents
   next cl
```

I want to copy the value first and paste it to the first available cell between Q36:Q47 before clearing it from its original cell

Comment: `range("a1").end(xlDown)` or `cells(rows.count,1).end(xlUp)` will be a good start, this goes from A1 to the next blank cell, or from the bottom of column A to the next row.  `cl.end(xlDown)` maybe for you.

Comment: Or even something like so `range("Q36:Q47").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1,1).row`